# css element hidden or displayed based on the height or overflow of another element

Tags: html, css

I have a list of rows with multiline content in some rows.

For the rows that are overflowing in multiple rows, I want to show an element for toggling the height, while I want to hide this toggle element for the rows with small content.

Is it possible to achieve this only with css and no javascript?

Html code should be pretty much anything to reach the goal, adding a jsfiddle just as starting point.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 820px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

div > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -25px;
}

label > i.toggle-off,
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input:checked ~ p {
  overflow: visible !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

input:checked ~ label > i.toggle-on {
  display: none;
}

input:checked ~ label > i.toggle-off {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
      
<h1>no js attempt, how to hide unuseful toggles?</h1>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-11">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-12" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-12">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-13" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-13">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-14" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-14">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-15" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-15">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-16" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-16">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-17" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-17">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-18" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-18">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwa3uk1p/2/

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: Added html as example but html could be pretty much anything to reach the goal :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do all of the above without javascript, best you can do with html/css only is toggling part, this way:

```css
.toggle-label {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
.hidden,
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .toggle-label {
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .toggle-content {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Light text</p>
<p>Long text 
    <input class="hidden" id="toggle-1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="toggle-label" for="toggle-1">read more</label>
    <span class="toggle-content">
        reavealed.
    </span>
</p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/svy9qt1g/)

Comment: It looks I was able to manage it, let me know if you like my solution, thanks!

Comment: Yes, a nice solution, though the toggle is outside of content... cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally managed it! Feedbacks are very welcome.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: calc(80% - 35px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*border: solid 1px blue;*/
}

p {
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 35px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: solid 1px orange;*/
}

p::after {
    content: '+';
    color: white;
    width: 55px;
    height: 35px;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: -35px;
    /*border: solid 1px red;*/
}

div > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -35px;
  /*border: solid 1px yellow;*/
}

label > i.toggle-off,
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input:checked ~ p {
  overflow: visible !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

input:checked ~ label > i.toggle-on {
  display: none;
}

input:checked ~ label > i.toggle-off {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-11" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-11">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-12" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-12">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-13" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-13">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-14" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-14">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-15" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-15">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-16" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-16">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-17" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-17">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-18" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-18">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='hidden' id="toggle-19" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle-19">
    <i class="material-icons toggle-on add_circle_outline">&#xe148;</i>
    <i class="material-icons toggle-off remove_circle_outline">&#xe15d;</i>
  </label>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse euismod, ligula ac tristique mollis, nunc odio malesuada dui, et pulvinar magna lorem sed sapien. Integer ac lobortis velit, fermentum rutrum diam. Phasellus placerat magna sit amet egestas iaculis. In ac maximus sapien. Suspendisse sapien nibh, accumsan nec varius et, tempor vitae felis. Etiam mattis nulla interdum erat porta pretium a a mauris. Duis erat nunc, congue quis dui quis, sagittis vulputate eros. Cras urna purus, commodo non metus eu, commodo fermentum lectus. Sed maximus, dolor eu porttitor sollicitudin, tellus augue ultricies magna, eu aliquet turpis justo a est. Sed elementum nunc sed mi rhoncus consequat. Morbi volutpat nec purus eget commodo.</p>
</div>
```